# JavaFx exported Jar doesn't show Images

Tags: java, javafx

Am using JavaFx with sceneBuilder when i export the project to a .Jar i dont get the images here is my Scene builder (Image,Path)(when i try to change the path in the scene builder its freez and crash) and the location of the Images (i tried all what is asked in SO but its dont work (everything works fine in the IDE but when i export its dont show the images ).

PS : am using the library handling : Package required libraries into generated Jar (for my Data base )

Scene builder : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk9zB.png)

Path : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsE1Y.png)

Exported Jar :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Akdf.png)

Comment: Try moving the image folder to the com package and updating the links in Scenebuilder.

Comment: You can also create a folder in the same folder as the Jar. Name it `Images` and put the images in there.

Comment: i want to export it inside the jar

Comment: Put it in the `com` package.

Comment: ok will try thanks

Comment: the folder i cant put it in the package but i can put the images one by one but still dont work even with this

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Not getting any error just cant see my images look the images i uploaded in my main topic

Comment: If the Images are not loading you should be getting errors. Try running the jar from the command line.

Comment: When you moved the images, did you make the adjustments in SceneBuilder and anywhere else you needed to?

Comment: look the right one its from eclipse (there is an image) the left one from a jar (with the command line there is no image and no error )http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/45/5/1541794525-ezezeze.png

Comment: Only thing I can think of is cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: hmmm ok thanks will see if any one else could help me ^^

Comment: So (rehello) i tried to put everything in the Package and extract it with the first option and its worked fine if i get any error later i will tell you and many thanks for the help ^^

Comment: For future reference, when an image fails to load the error will likely be put into the [`exception` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#exceptionProperty).